# outgoing mail using gmail not working in moodle after google removed permission for less secure apps

Tags: email

outgoing mail using gmail not working in moodle after google removed permission for less secure apps. Error: "Your site couldn't communicate with your mail server. Please check your outgoing mail configuration."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get the google smtp working by the following step.

1. visit https://myaccount.google.com/
2. turn on 2-step verification
3. create App password
4. use App password in step 3 in moodle outgoing mail setting